# PDF - @Page CSS - Add margin top in all pages

Tags: css, pdf, itext, margin

I am generating the PDF using iText. I need to give space between the header and main content.

@page {margin: 12mm 25mm 15mm 25mm; @top-center {content: element(header) }}

Please help me[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCcT2.png)

Comment: Please tell (and show) us how you create your document. Do you use pdfHTML add-on?

Comment: I did from JAVA iText and got solution by setting  margin in @page and header in CSS

Comment: the problem is resolved then, right?

Could you post your own answer and accept it or at least mention it somehow in the question's description that no more help is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding margin in @page and .header in CSS